# From a monoid ring to a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to understand what a tableaux ring is (it's not clear to me reading Young Tableaux by Fulton).

I studied what a monoid ring is on Serge Lang's Algebra, and then I read about modules, modules homomorphism. I'm trying to prove what is stated at page 121 (S. Lang, Algebra) while talking about algebras: "we note that the group ring $A[G]$ (or monoid ring when $G$ is a monoid) is an $A$-algebra, also called group (or monoid) algebra."

Correct me if I'm wrong, I believe that i should start proving that the monoid ring $A[G]$ (here $G$ is a monoid) is an $A$-module. Well I can't figure out how it could be! This is what i've tried:

notation: $A$ ring, $G$ monoid, $a \in A, x \in G$. 
$a \cdot x$ is the map $G \rightarrow A$ such that $a \cdot x (x) = a$ and $a \cdot x (y) = 0$ for every $y \neq x$

$(a+b) \cdot x = a \cdot x + b\cdot x$ for every $a,b \in A$ and every $x \in G$ follows from definition of $a \cdot x$. I don't know how to show $a \cdot (x+y) = a \cdot x + a \cdot y$, honestly I'm about to think it is not true.

Thanks in advance,

sciamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Lang, you consider $A[G]$ as a set of functions $\alpha:G\to A$. Then $\beta=a\cdot\alpha$ is a new function with values $\beta (x)=a\alpha (x)$. Then, e.g., the equality $(a+b)\alpha=a\alpha+b\alpha$ is evident.

Comment: Yes it's evident, I was trying to prove the wrong thing! Of course $\alpha \in A[G]$, don't know why but I was trying with $\alpha \in G$.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As an $A$-module we have $A[G]:=\bigoplus_{g \in G} A$, i.e. it is the free $A$-module with basis $G$. So actually there is nothing to prove when you already know direct sums.

Your definition is incomplete, since you only define the $A$-module action on the basis elements of $G$. The complete definition is

$$a \cdot \sum_{g \in G} r_g \cdot g := \sum_{g \in G} (a \cdot r_g) \cdot g$$